# How to add map to a custom entity in MSCRM 2015 and how to plot multiple locations on it?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

How to add map to a custom entity in MSCRM 2015 and how to plot multiple locations on it ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know more details about your situation, what you're trying to accomplish, what mapping tool you're trying to use.  Without that the best I can do is offer some basic suggestions...

1. Making the assumption that you're going to use the Bing maps ajax control, you can put a map on a custom entity's form using a html web resource in combination with some javascript to manage the map control.  [Here](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7) is the Bing maps interactive SDK where you can play around with some different features of the map control to plot points, etc.  And [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx) is the Bing Maps MSDN area where you can get into the details on how to use the control.
2. To put some points on the map, assuming the data you want to use is related to the entity record/form currently open, you can use the javascript provided as part of the CRM SDK to retrieve data directly off the form or current record, or do some ajax calls to the CRM OData endpoint to retrieve the necessary data and finally plot that data on the map.